# How to get DB password from Azure app vault using python ? I am running this python file on google Dataproc cluster

Tags: python, azure, google-cloud-dataproc

My Sql server DB password is saved on Azure app vault which has DATAREF ID as a identifier. I need that password to create spark dataframe from table which is present in SQL server. I am running this .py file on google Dataproc cluster. How can I get that password using python?

Comment: Admittedly didn't try this out, but my first stop would be the [Azure Key Vault Secret library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python?tabs=azure-cli) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing an Azure service from a non-Azure service, you will need a service principal. You can use certificate or secret. See [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python#authenticate-service-principals) link for the different methods. You will need to give the service principal proper access and this will depend if you are using RBAC or access policy for your key vault.
So the steps you need to follow are:

1. Create a key vault and create a secret.
2. Create a Service principal or application registration. Store the clientid, clientsecret and tenantid.
3. Give the service principal proper access to the key vault(if you are using access policies) or to the specific secret(if you are using RBAC model)

The python link for the code is [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/keyvault-secrets-readme?view=azure-python).
The code that will work for you is below:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
tenantid = <your_tenant_id>
clientsecret = <your_client_secret>
clientid = <your_client_id>

my_credentials = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenantid, client_id=clientid, client_secret=clientsecret)

secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://<your_keyvault_name>.vault.azure.net/", credential=my_credentials)
secret = secret_client.get_secret("<your_secret_name>")

print(secret.name)
print(secret.value)
```